# Where does the csrf_token() function come from in flask_wtf.csrf?

Tags: python, flask, csrf

I've implemented a flask app and needed to use a CSRF token. The code looks something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

The jinja templating uses the csrf_token() function, which I assumed was coming from Python. However, the function isn't imported or initialized anywhere, so I was wondering if maybe it's initialized when the CSRFProtect function is run? It looks like this when we import and initialize things:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

The docs are here: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/csrf/

Comment: It's not a plain Python function, it's a Jinja extension registered with your Jinja instance somewhere.

Comment: Ah ok. So the jinja instance is something running as a process/thread somewhere (as a Python thread?) and something is somehow initializing that extension with the function (probably the flask_wtf init function).

Comment: No, not a thread, just an object instance of the Twig class.

Answer (score 1):

In flask_wtf/csrf.py you find the init_app method that registers the context_processor with jinja. "csrf_token" maps to the generate_csrf() function in the same file:

```
def init_app(self, app):
    // ...
    app.jinja_env.globals["csrf_token"] = generate_csrf
```

That's an excerpt of the csrf.py file.